# Classical characterization of Lie groups.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-groups

Somebody told me that Lie groups can be understood as smooth manifolds with a simple transitive (algebraic)-group of transformations defined on it (e.g right-translations). Moreover, if the manifold $M$ is connected, one can consider a Lie group structure on $M$ as a  transitive Lie algebra action of complete vector fields.

Is there a classical reference for these characterisation of Lie groups?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A group of Lie is called a Lawyer

Comment: What you wrote is not quite right. The correct statement is that given a subgroup $G$ of the diffeomorphism group of $M$ acting simply transitively on $M$, $G$ has a Lie group structure such that each orbit map $G\to Gx=M$ is a diffeomorphism. It is a nice exercise to prove.

Comment: Many thanks for the support. I will try to prove the exercise!